# I just saw a bright light with white trails in the night sky, what was it?

Tags: everyday-life, rocket-science

[image: Seen two hours after subset, what was it?]

I was driving home two hour after sunset and I saw this light above the horizon? Was it a satellite or a meteorite, I would like to know.

Comment: If you were to describe how it was moving in detail to the best of your abilities we might be able to better narrow down what it might have been.

Comment: https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2017/12/spacex-2017-campaign-iridium-4-launch/

Comment: If I didn't happen to just see another photo of the same thing at the above link, I'd be asking you for some basic information you didn't include: Where did you see it? What day did you see it on? What direction were you looking in?

Comment: I think a beyond the short answer, some answers about this particular rocket,  its mission and why it produced such a spectacular show would be cool.

Comment: It's the timing: just after sunset. We're in the dark, and the upper atmosphere is not. The grizzled NASA veterans say this was the most spectacular and dynamic exhaust trail they've ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to go out an look-it was a VAFB launch of a space X falcon:

http://www.latimes.com/local/lanow/la-me-space-x-sky-20171222-story.html